# Duda con QTranslator

Tags: c++, qt

Creo una pequeña interfaz de prueba compuesta por dos botones,una tabla y un combobox para cambiar el idioma. Todo sin Designer.

```
botonRedo = new QPushButton(QIcon("../Prueba/iconos/rehacer.png"),tr("Rehacer"));
botonUndo = new QPushButton(QIcon("../Prueba/iconos/deshacer.png"),tr("Deshacer"));

comboLenguajes= new QComboBox;
QStringList listaIdiomas;
listaIdiomas<<tr("Español")<<tr("Ingles");
comboLenguajes->addItems(listaIdiomas);

Object::connect(comboLenguajes,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this,SLOT(CambiarIdioma(int)));
```

El widget de prueba tiene una tabla con esta cabecera:

```
cabecera<<tr("Amigo")<<tr("Ciudad")<<tr("Color")<<tr("Sexo");
```

La función (slot) a la que llama el combobox es ésta:

```
void Widget::CambiarIdioma(int indice)
{
    QString filename = "/home/Otras/programacion/Qt/MVC/Prueba/Prueba/prueba_en";
    if (indice==1)
    {        
        listaTranslator.load(filename);
        qApp->installTranslator(&listaTranslator);
    }
    else
    {
        qApp->removeTranslator(&listaTranslator);
    }
}
```

Y por último tengo creado este evento:

```
void Widget::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange)
    {
        CambiarTraduccion();
    }
    QWidget::changeEvent(event);
}
```

Que llama a esta función:

```
void Widget::CambiarTraduccion()
{
    botonRedo->setText(tr("redo"));
    botonUndo->setText(tr("undo"));
    QStringList nombresIngles;
    nombresIngles<<tr("Name")<<tr("City")<<tr("Colour")<<tr("Sex");
    modelo->TraducirCabecera(nombresIngles);

}
```

La traducción está creada por otro lado con QLinguist, el cual me ha creado el archivo *.qm correspondiente.

El caso es que cuando cambio del idioma primero (español) mediante e combobox, la cosa funciona y pasa todo al inglés, pero cuando vuelvo a ponerlo en español no funciona. Además creo que debo tener algún problema conceptual, porque no sé por qué he de traducir e incluir el fichero de traducción, cuando luego tengo que crear una función ad hoc para incluir las traducciones. Algo se me escapa.

Answer (score 0):

La traducción no funciona como planteas y prueba de ello es que puedes eliminar todas las llamadas a `tr` y el ejemplo funcionará exactamente igual.

Cuando tu pones una cadena tal que:

```
QObject::tr("algo");
```

Qt utilizará esa cadena como identificador a la hora de buscar traducciones.

Una vez que ya has modificado la aplicación para que todas las cadenas traducibles hagan uso de `tr` lo que toca es abrir *QtLinguist* y crear un fichero de idioma por cada traducción que se quiera aplicar (si quieres volver en tiempo de ejecución a los textos originales tendrás que crear un fichero de traducción para los mismos).

Para añadir los ficheros de traducción al proyecto tienes que editar el fichero del proyecto:

```
TRANSLATIONS = languages/translation_en.ts  languages/translation_es.ts
```

Y ahora, para cambiar el fichero de traducción utilizado en cada momento tienes que utilizar `removeTranslator` e `installTranslator`

```
QTranslator translator;

// eliminar la traduccion antigua
qApp->removeTranslator(&translator);

// cargar la nueva
qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
```

Y con esto la traducción de los textos se realizará de forma automática.

Tienes a tu disposición un tutorial sobre este tema en el siguiente [enlace](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application)